# There is a problem with the gets function in c programming language

Tags: c, structure, fgets, gets

I'm creating a simple program using the C programming language.
Unfortunately, I'm having a problem with a piece of source code right now.
I am not able to store data in the students structure after running the program.

I think the problem is the gets() function in the ADD_Students() function. (Line 60)

Here is my source code: (Used code blocks with gnu gcc compiler in windows 10)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define MAX 3

struct Students
{
    char * Name;
    char * Field;
    char * City;

    unsigned int Student_ID;
    float Mark;
}Addr_INFO[MAX];


char Menu();
void ADD_Students();
void DEL_Students();
void EDT_Students();

int main()
{
    char Selected_ITEM;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        Selected_ITEM = Menu();

        switch (Selected_ITEM)
        {
            case '1' : ADD_Students(); break;
            case '2' : DEL_Students(); break;
            case '3' : EDT_Students(); break;
            default : printf("Wrong number!\n"); exit(0);
        }
    }
}


char Menu()
{
    char Chose;

    printf(".----------+ Students information management +----------.\n\n");
    printf("[1]. ADD student\n");
    printf("[2]. DEL student\n");
    printf("[3]. EDT student\n\n");

    printf("Please enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%c", &Chose);

    return Chose;
}


void ADD_Students()
{
    register int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("[S-%d]. Name: ", i);
        gets(Addr_INFO[i].Name);
        printf("[S-%d]. Field: ", i);
        gets(Addr_INFO[i].Field);
        printf("[S-%d]. City: ", i);
        gets(Addr_INFO[i].City);
        printf("[S-%d]. ID: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &Addr_INFO[i].Student_ID);
        printf("[S-%d]. Mark: ", i);
        scanf("%.2f", &Addr_INFO[i].Mark);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void DEL_Students()
{
    printf("Test2");
}


void EDT_Students()
{
    printf("Test3");
}
```

what's going on?

Why this is happened?

Ouput

```
.----------+ Students information management +----------.

[1]. ADD student
[2]. DEL student
[3]. EDT student

Please enter your choice: 1
[S-0]. Name: [S-0]. Field: [S-0]. City: [S-0]. ID:
```

Comment: Please explain the nature of the problem; if you get an error message, what does it say?  If it produces the wrong result, what is it an what should it be?  When you run it with a debugger, what is the *first* thing the program does incorrectly?

Comment: The `scanf()` call leaves the newline in the input buffer. Therefore, `gets()` reads up to the first newline.  And you should NOT be using `gets()` ever!  Never, never, never, *never*, **never**, ***NEVER*** use `gets()`!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- Is there [a problem with the `gets()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)? ;)

Comment: It is deprecated - also suffers from buffer overflows

Comment: Jonathan Leffler , So what function should I use to get the string?

Comment: Use `fgets()`, but you’ll still need to deal with the newline left over from `scanf()` and `%c`.  And the newline included in the input by `fgets()`.  The Q&A linked to by ex nihilo explains the problemcc GCC and the alternatives.

Comment: You should be able to reduce this to a [mcve] of your problem, without all the extraneous parts (`struct Students` etc.).

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but it's a good idea to make all your function declarations *prototypes* - i.e. specify what arguments they take; `(void)` if no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your code.
You are passing an uninitialized pointer to `gets`.

You never add an actual bit of memory to your `Addr_INFO` entries.
You should either declare the members as an array of some appropriate size or `gets` the data into a local buffer and then allocate memory (`malloc`) of sufficient size and copy the local data to that buffer and assign its pointer you to the member.

Comment: That’s one of the problems. There are at least two others, one being the use of `gets()` at all.

Comment: `gets` should be `fgets` at least

Answer (score 1):

First problem - **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets`.  It has been removed from the standard library as of the 2011 standard, and it *will* (not might, *will*) introduce a point of failure in your program.  It is the programming equivalent of plutonium.  Use `fgets` instead:

```
if ( fgets(Addr_INFO[i].Name, MAX_NAME_LEN, stdin) == NULL )
  // error on input
else
  // process Addr_INFO[i].Name
```

Second problem - you never set aside any memory to actually *store* a name, field, or city.  All you've done is declare the pointers, but you never set them to point anywhere meaningful.  They initially contain some random bit pattern that very likely doesn't correspond to a valid address.

For a simple program like this, it's probably better to declare those fields as arrays of `char`, rather than just pointers:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN  40 // or whatever you expect the longest name to be
#define MAX_FIELD_LEN 40 // same as above
#define MAX_CITY_LEN  40 // same as above 

struct Students
{
    char Name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];  // +1 for string terminator
    char Field[MAX_FIELD_LEN + 1];
    char City[MAX_CITY_LEN + 1];

    unsigned int Student_ID;
    float Mark;
}Addr_INFO[MAX];
```

And then your `fgets` call changes ever-so-slightly to

```
if ( fgets( AddrInfo[i].Name, sizeof AddrInfo[i].Name, stdin ) == NULL )
  // error on input
else
  // process AddrInfo[i].Name
```